# how to check page is valid then show confirmed dialog for delete in jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have this script:

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
    function ConfirmDelete() {
        if (Page_ClientValidate("ischecked")) {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            } else {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server"  
OnClick="imgbtnDelete_Click" OnClientClick = "ConfirmDelete()"
CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" 
ImageUrl="~/images/forDesign/Grid_ActionDelete.gif" />
```

I want , first check that page is valid then show confirm for delete.
but this just check page is valid and don't show confirm dialog